Show $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \zeta(2m) - \zeta(2m + 2k) \right) = \sum_{m=1}^k \zeta(2m) - k$
I noticed this pattern using WolframAlpha that
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \zeta(2m) - \zeta(2m + 2k) \right) = \sum_{m=1}^k \zeta(2m) - k
$$
I've tried to prove it as follows:
\begin{align}
 \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \zeta(2m) - \zeta(2m + 2k) \right)
&=  \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n^{2m}} - \frac{1}{n^{2m + 2k}} \right) \\
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n^{2m}} - \frac{1}{n^{2m + 2k}} \right) \\
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2m}} - \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2m + 2k}} \right) \\
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n^2 - 1} - \frac{1}{n^{2k}(n^2 - 1)} \right) \\
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^{2k} - 1}{n^{2k}(n^2 - 1)} \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^k \zeta(2m) - k 
\end{align}
but, to complete the proof, I'm curious how WolframAlpha determines that
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^{2k} - 1}{n^{2k}(n^2 - 1)} = \sum_{m=1}^k \zeta(2m) - k$$
Update:
Based on the comments, we have
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \zeta(2m) - \zeta(2m + 2k) \right) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^{2k} - 1}{n^{2k}(n^2 - 1)} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1 - n^{-2k}}{n^2 - 1} \tag{1}$$
and
$$\sum_{m=1}^k \zeta(2m) = \sum_{m=1}^k \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2m}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^k \frac{1}{n^{2m}}$$
For $n=1$,
$$\sum_{m=1}^k \frac{1}{1^{2m}} = k$$
For $n \ge 2$,
$$\sum_{m=1}^k \frac{1}{n^{2m}} = \frac{1 - n^{-2k}}{n^2 - 1}$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{m=1}^k \zeta(2m) = k + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1 - n^{-2k}}{n^2 - 1}$$
So,
$$\sum_{m=1}^k \zeta(2m) - k = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1 - n^{-2k}}{n^2 - 1} \tag{2}$$
Finally, comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \zeta(2m) - \zeta(2m + 2k) \right) = \sum_{m=1}^k \zeta(2m) - k
$$
References:
Show $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\zeta(2m) - \zeta(2m+1)\right) = \frac{1}{2}$

$$\frac{n^{2k}-1}{n^2-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}n^{2j}=n^{2k}\sum_{m=1}^k n^{-2m}.$$

Is the $-k$ coming from $\zeta(2m + 2k) \to 1$ as $m \to \infty$ and there are $k$ such terms?

The sum over $n$ is from $\color{blue}{n=2}$, leading to $\zeta(\dots)\color{blue}{-1}$.

If $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}a_m=0$ then $\sum_{m=1}^\infty(a_m-a_{m+k})=\sum_{m=1}^k a_m$ (for a proof, consider finite sums...).
Now apply this to $a_m=\zeta(2m)-1$ (so, riemann-zeta is basically a distraction here).

Thanks! Based on your answer, let $a_m=\zeta(2m)-1$ and the result follows:
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty ((\zeta(2m) - 1) - (\zeta(2m + 2k) - 1)) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty (\zeta(2m) - \zeta(2m + 2k)) = \sum_{m=1}^k (\zeta(2m) - 1) = \sum_{m=1}^k \zeta(2m) - \sum_{m=1}^k 1 = \sum_{m=1}^k \zeta(2m) - k$$
